# How to restyle a TabControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-interface, tabcontrol

I am new in WPF. Here I am posting a picture of a `TabControl`. Just guide me how can I re-style a tab having same UI in WPF as per my picture.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you will need to implement a `Style` / `Template` for `TabControl` to get this form. `TabControl` has three directions for the tabs are: central (*`default`*), left and right directions. You need to left direction, judging by picture.

Style for `TabItem` (elements of `TabControl`) would be one in all directions.

Style for `TabControl` with *left* direction:

```
<Style x:Key="LeftTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid ClipToBounds="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Name="ColumnDefinition0" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0" Name="ColumnDefinition1" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="RowDefinition0" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" Name="RowDefinition1" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Background="#FAFAFA" Margin="0">
                            <TabPanel IsItemsHost="True" Name="HeaderPanel" Panel.ZIndex="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                        </Border>

                        <Grid Name="ContentPanel" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedContent}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectedContentTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectedContentStringFormat}" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabControl.TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter TargetName="HeaderPanel" Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentPanel" Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="HeaderPanel" Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentPanel" Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" Value="*" />
                            <Setter TargetName="RowDefinition0" Property="RowDefinition.Height" Value="*" />
                            <Setter TargetName="RowDefinition1" Property="RowDefinition.Height" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="HeaderBorder" Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Style for `TabItem`:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="./#Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Name="Border" Margin="0,0,2,0" Padding="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0">
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" ContentSource="Header" />
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>               
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F5B79C" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>

            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DB805A" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </MultiTrigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

`MainWindow`

```
<TabControl Style="{StaticResource LeftTabControl}" Background="Gainsboro" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TabItem Header="New">
        <Label Content="TestNew" />
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Old">
        <Label Content="TestOld" />
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Recent">
        <Label Content="RecentHelp" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

`Output`

[image]

To add a triangle selection, you need to fix a template for `TabItem`. Add `Path` with triangle and display it in the current `TabItem`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Name="Border" Margin="0,0,2,0" Padding="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0">
        <Grid>
            <Path x:Name="CurrentTriangle" Width="10" Height="14" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,-3,0" Fill="#FAFAFA" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 287.328,237.333L 319.344,255.818L 319.344,218.849L 287.328,237.333 Z " Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" ContentSource="Header" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        ...

        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="CurrentTriangle" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Output with Triangle:

[image]

Full listing of `TabItem` style with `Triangle`:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="./#Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Name="Border" Margin="0,0,2,0" Padding="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Path x:Name="CurrentTriangle" Width="10" Height="14" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,-3,0" Fill="#FAFAFA" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 287.328,237.333L 319.344,255.818L 319.344,218.849L 287.328,237.333 Z " Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" ContentSource="Header" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="CurrentTriangle" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>               
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F5B79C" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>

            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DB805A" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </MultiTrigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

`Edit:` I'll tell you in order.

All of the `Styles`, that I have given above are placed in `App.xaml` like that (it is desirable that they were there):

```
<Application x:Class="SomeProgram.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" 
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LeftTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
     ...
    </Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type TabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
     ...
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

> Specify the picture path for `Triangle`.

By default, the template for `TabItem` looks like this:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Name="Border" Margin="0,0,2,0" Padding="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0">
            <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" ContentSource="Header" />
        </Border>
```

The `ContentPresenter` responsible for displaying the contents, in this case for displaying the text in the header. But we need to have displayed a triangle, so add him as a figure `Path`:

```
<Path x:Name="CurrentTriangle" Width="10" Height="14" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,-3,0" Fill="#FAFAFA" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 287.328,237.333L 319.344,255.818L 319.344,218.849L 287.328,237.333 Z " Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

This is not the `Image`, the `Path` is easier to use, no need to keep the resource. More information you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx).

So, now we have a triangle appears, but we need to show it when the tab will be selected. For this we use a trigger to do it:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="CurrentTriangle" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
</Trigger>
```

More information about triggers you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.triggers.aspx).

> Gradient back color for selected `TabItem`.

Color for selected `TabItem` also sets in Trigger of `TabItem` style:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F5B79C" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
</Trigger>
```

Here sets the values of `Background` and `Foreground` of selected `TabItem`. Gradient color define like that:

```
<LinearGradientBrush>
    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
    <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.5" />
    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1.0" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

You need to set your gradient color for the property `Background` in trigger.

> Background for TabControl

`Background` is set for the `TabControl's` style this line:

```
<Style x:Key="LeftTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
```

More information about Brushes (Gradient's) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx).

Information about styles/templates [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx).

Comment: thanks for nice help. i am weak in wpf. so like to ask where u specify the picture path for triangle.what kind of code one need to add to have that kind of gradient back color for selected tab item. what kind of code i need to add to have gradient color for tab background like mixture of gray & white.

Comment: can u help me to generate two gradient. one is blue gradient for active tab item and another one is tab background which mixed white gradient. here i tried to generate one gradient but it does not look like above one. here is the code. <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="radial"
  Center="0.52,0.48" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" 
  SpreadMethod="Pad" ColorInterpolationMode="ScRgbLinearInterpolation" >
  <GradientStop Color="#FF183EEF" Offset="0" />
  <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="1" />
</RadialGradientBrush>

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. 
Add a tab control on you window then set the TabStripPlacement to Left. then add some tab items to this tab control. Now add Style in  Windows.Resource section.

```
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TabItemFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNormalBorderBrush}"/>

        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.019,0.518" RadiusY="0.741" RadiusX="0.578" Center="0.019,0.518">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC5C7C8" Offset="0.47"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD1D3D8"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E2E2" Offset="1"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Grid x:Name="grd" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="40">
                            <Path x:Name="CurrentTriangle" Width="10" Height="14" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,-3,0" Fill="#FAFAFA" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 287.328,237.333L 319.344,255.818L 319.344,218.849L 287.328,237.333 Z " Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>    

                            </Grid>                             
                        </Border>                       
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHotBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="CurrentTriangle"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd">

                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.501,0.914" RadiusY="0.419" RadiusX="0.355" Center="0.501,0.914">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF082876" Offset="0.727"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF1145C4" Offset="0.221"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0E245C" Offset="1"/>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="Silver"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>



                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBackground}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBorderBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

for a custom Tab header you can use Header Template. a custom template will be good in this. case .  some thing like

```
<TabControl   TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="005_Task_24x24_72.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sample Tab"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="008_Reminder_24x24.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sample Tab"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
            <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="023_Tip_16x16_72.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sample Tab"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="1409_Monitor_24x24.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sample Tab"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
            <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="FavoriteStar_FrontFacing_24x24_72.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sample Tab"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="Music_Note_Double_24.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sample Tab"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
            <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="005_Task_24x24_72.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sample Tab"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="005_Task_24x24_72.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sample Tab"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
            <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="005_Task_24x24_72.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sample Tab"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="005_Task_24x24_72.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sample Tab"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: can u help me to generate two gradient. one is blue gradient for active tab item and another one is tab background which mixed white gradient. here i tried to generate one gradient but it does not look like above one. here is the code. <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="radial"
  Center="0.52,0.48" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" 
  SpreadMethod="Pad" ColorInterpolationMode="ScRgbLinearInterpolation" >
  <GradientStop Color="#FF183EEF" Offset="0" />
  <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="1" />
</RadialGradientBrush>